# Rails assets:precompile does not compile requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

For some reason, after running rake `assets:precompile`, `require` statements in `application.js` are left untouched. Here is how *compiled* `application.js` looks like:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_directory .
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require rails.validations

$(document).on("click", '.show', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-big-url');
$('.image_container img').attr('src', value);
return false;
});
```

That `//= require` statements should be substituted!

Any ideas?..

THanks!

**EDIT**: uncompiled `application.js`:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_directory .
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require rails.validations

$(document).on("click", '.show', function(e) {
var value = $(this).attr('data-big-url');
$('.image_container img').attr('src', value);
return false;
});

// $(window).load(function() {
//    $('#featured').orbit();
//   // $('#featured-bg').orbit();
```

...

It looks exactly the same!

Here is my `production.rb`:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = false
```

Comment: what does the uncompiled file look like?

Comment: Here it is! I update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve the issue:

I had to downgrade to Ruby 1.9.3.

Unfortunately, I still don't know what was the reason of the issue, but now I have my assets compiling correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I don't believe you'd want `require ____` in a precompiled JS file

> The reason is the `require` lines are called *directives* which guide
>   the creation of a `manifest.json` file for your assets. The
>   [manifest](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) basically tells Rails which files make up your assets,
>   allowing it to compile them effectively

You can see the precompiling documenation from the Rails guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) - basically says that the files you get from precompilation are "standalone" files. They are meant to be loaded as static files, without any preprocessors or directives

I would try this:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will compile the files as if it were the production environment, and storing them in `/public/assets` as a naked JS / CSS file

Comment: Thanks, absolutely, I **DON'T** want that `require` to show up. `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` produce files with `require`

Comment: Hmm - have you tried removing your other options including `config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = false`?